# How to connect a final linear layer correctly when using Multivariate Time series forecasting with pytorch LSTM,?

Tags: python, pytorch, time-series, lstm, forecasting

Given a simple multivariate time series problem

```
l = [ list(range(1000)),list(range(1000,2000)),list(range(2000,3000)), list(range(3000,4000)), list(range(4000,5000))]

df = pd.DataFrame(l).T
df.columns = ['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3', 'feat_4', 'feat_5']

target_sensor = 'feat_5'
```

If We want to predict the value of  `target_sensor` in t+forecast_lead time steps

```
forecast_lead = 15
print('\nforecast_lead', forecast_lead)

target = f"{target_sensor}_TARGET{forecast_lead}"
features = list(df.columns.difference([target]))

df[target] = df[target_sensor].shift(-forecast_lead)
df = df.iloc[:-forecast_lead]
```

The input preparation is based on this `torch.Dataset` class:

```
class My_Dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe, target, features, sequence_length):
        self.features = features    #list of columns
        self.target = target        #str target col name 
        self.sequence_length = sequence_length    #history we want to use
        self.X = torch.tensor(dataframe[features].values).float()  #to tensor
        self.y = torch.tensor(dataframe[target].values).float()    #to tensor

    def __len__(self):
        return self.X.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, i): 
        if i >= self.sequence_length - 1:
            i_start = i - self.sequence_length + 1
            x = self.X[i_start:(i + 1), :]
        else:
            padding = self.X[0].repeat(self.sequence_length - i - 1, 1)
            x = self.X[0:(i + 1), :]
            x = torch.cat((padding, x), 0)

        return x, self.y[i]
```

With the following Dataloader (batch_size =1 ) for simplicity.

```
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False,num_workers=1)
test_loader  = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, num_workers=1)
```

The Model I am using is this:

```
class LSTM_Multivariate_Time_Series_Regression(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, num_features, hidden_size):
    super().__init__()
    self.num_feture= num_features  # this is the number of features
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = 1   # OR MORE THAN 1 HERE

    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size=num_features,
                        hidden_size=hidden_size,
                        batch_first=True,
                        num_layers=self.num_layers
                        )

    self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features=self.hidden_size,
                            out_features=1)
```

In the forward pass if NUM_LAYER = 1

```
  def forward(self, x):
    lstm_output , (hn, cn) = self.lstm(x)
    out = self.linear(hn[0]) # First dim of Hn is num_layers, which is set to 1 above.
```

In the forward pass, before passing through the **Linear Layer** IF SELF.NUM_LAYER > 1, I suppose following options are available

1. Use the last hidden state `hn[-1]`
2. Use the concatenation of all hidden state

   ```
   #Docs WITH BATCH FIRST = TRUE : lstm_output tensor of shape: (BATCH_SIZE , SEQ_LENGHT, HIDDEN_SIZE)
   #docs WITH BATCH FIRST  h_n: tensor of shape (NUM_LAYER, BATCH_SIZE, HIDDEN_SIZE)  containing the final hidden state for each element in the batch
   ```

.1

```
out = self.linear(hn[-1]).flatten()
return out
```

Is a correct solution to add final Linear layer to the lstm layer  this way?

Comment: Because this question is less concerned with programming and more with classification methodology and/or training parameters it is better suited for the [Data Science](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/). Please read the relevant guidance related to how to properly ask questions on this site before posting your question.

Comment: There is no clear answer for this, because it is problem-specific. Do experimentation with the final cell state, hidden state, and pooled (average, max?) outputs of your LSTM to see what works best.